# How to copy paste information to another worksheet on exact rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with my macros. The idea of this code is that I have one worksheet with big data about clients and multiple sheets which names are salesman's names. I want to copy and paste information about clients based on their salesman. In those salesman worksheet I have two places where I want to paste all clients: from 10th row in each worksheet I want to paste clients according to this condition `If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = salesmanName And ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid"`. From 39 row in each worksheet I want to paste all clients with this condition `ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = salesmanName And Not ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid" Then`. Now with my code I get all clients of salesman from row 39 in each worksheet, maybe some of you will be able to help me to fix this problem.

```
Sub ExtractClientsBySalesman()
    ' Declare variables for the worksheet and last row of data
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsMatch As Worksheet

    ' Set the worksheet variable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
    

    ' Find the last row of data in the "data" worksheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through the data in column "D" (client)
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if the value in column "salesman" (column "E") matches "name_surname"
        For Each wsMatch In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Dim pasteRow As Long
            Dim pasteRow2 As Long
            pasteRow = 10
            pasteRow2 = 39
            salesmanName = wsMatch.Range("A5").Value
            
            If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = salesmanName And ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid" Then
             ' Copy the client information to the new worksheet
                pasteRow = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ' Copy the client information to the worksheet
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 42).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, 40).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value
                
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = salesmanName And Not ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid" Then
                pasteRow2 = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ' Copy the client information to the worksheet
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 42).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, 40).Value
                wsMatch.Cells(pasteRow2, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value
                
            End If
        Next wsMatch
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, place `pasteRow  = pasteRow +1` before `ElseIf` and `pasteRow2 = pasteRow2 + 1` before `End If`... You need to increment each such variable after using (to paste on the next row).

Comment: still the same problem, all values were pasted from row 39 in each worksheet

Comment: Not **only** in cases where `ws.Cells(i, "I").Value <> "valid"`? In fact, I can see another way of updating the variables... Please, comment the  lines `pasteRow = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` and `pasteRow2 = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`, But, just to be sure: don't you want pasting starting from the 10th row in one case and starting from 39th row in the other one? The way you calculated the variables has nothing to do with their initial name. They are calculated according to the last existing row...

Comment: Yes, it should be like that: pasting should starting from the 10th row in one case and starting from 39th row in the other one. 9th and 38th row are headers

Comment: So, did you comment the lines I suggested above? If so, doesn't it work as you need?

Comment: When I try comment those lines You suggested, then only one value (one row with information about client) is pasted per one condition, but I know from data that there should be more clients than just one

Comment: But this only means that you did not keep the variables incrementing I suggested in my first comment... "insert `pasteRow  = pasteRow +1` before `ElseIf` and `pasteRow2 = pasteRow2 + 1` before `End If`". I you do as I suggested, no matter that there are headers on column A:A. The variables will be incremented after each use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** It's better deal with next available line with different code. It's easier!
**2)** Also it's healthier that you exclude `data` worksheet from salesman worksheets.
**3)** It is advisable to use the `Option Explicit` clause to force to declare variables explicitly.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractClientsBySalesman()
 ' Declare variables for the worksheet and last row of data
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim wsMatch As Worksheet
  Dim valid As Boolean
  Dim lPaste As Long
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim salesmanName As String
  
' Initial line for each condition
  Dim pasteRow As Long
  Dim pasteRow2 As Long
  pasteRow = 10
  pasteRow2 = 39

' Set the worksheet variable
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
        
' Find the last row of data in the "data" worksheet
  lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

 ' Loop through the data in column "D" (client)
   For i = 2 To lastRow
   ' column "salesman" (column "E") matches "name_surname"?
     For Each wsMatch In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       If wsMatch.Name <> "data" Then
         salesmanName = wsMatch.Range("A5").Value
         lPaste = 0
         If ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = salesmanName Then
           valid = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid"
           If valid Then
            ' 1st section between lines 10 and 37. 
            ' Line 38 is 2nd section header
              lPaste = pasteRow2 - 2 
              ' 1st section after line 37 is invalid!
              If Not IsEmpty(wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 1).Value) Then
                MsgBox ("Data overflow at first section")
                End ' Exit from program
              End If
              ' 1st available line between 10 and 37
              lPaste = wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 1).End(xlUp).Row
              lPaste = Application.Max(pasteRow, lPaste + 1)
           Else
              ' 1st available line after line 39
              lPaste = wsMatch.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
              lPaste = Application.Max(pasteRow2, lPaste + 1)
           End If
         End If ' Same salesman

       ' Copy the client information to the new worksheet
         If (lPaste > 0) Then ' Same Salesman
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 42).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, 40).Value
           wsMatch.Cells(lPaste, 8).Value = ws.Cells(i, 12).Value
         End If  ' Same Salesman
       End If  ' Other workshets than 'data'
     Next wsMatch
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested because there is no data example, but my guess is that **first time** you got `ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid"` it should go to row 10 and from now on row 11, 12 and so on.

Same for `Not ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "valid"`: first match should go to 39 and then later to 40, 41 and so on.

If cells A9 and A38 are headers row and they are **not empty** you could try this:

Replace `pasteRow = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

with `pasteRow = wsMatch.Range("A38").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Your code does not work properly because if there is something in A38, when you do `pasteRow = wsMatch.Cells(wsMatch.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` it will stop at row 38 and that would explain why you got everything into A39.

Comment: I tried to change as You said, but I get error: "run-time error: 5: invalid procedure call or argument ". But You were right, A9 and A38 are headers, they are not empty

Comment: Sorry, i used `Cells`when it should be `Range` because I'm using A1 notation. @Laura_777 Check updated answer

Comment: Now all values are pasted in random places, so it is not really what I want

Comment: *Now all values are pasted in random places* This makes no sense, Please, edit your original question and add some data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult for me because I don't see the data and the expected result in some sheets. Anyway this is not directly the answer to your question, but my guess is something like this :

Table in sheets "DATA" is something like this:
[image]

Another sheets (sheet2 to sheet4) is something like this :
[image]

Expected result is something like this :
[image]

In short, to each sheets other than sheet DATA, get the name value in cell A5, then get range of cells in column L sheet DATA which contains that name. Within this range.offset(0,-3) ---> (column I), to each cell with "Valid" value row Nth, fill the looped sheet (column A to C) start from row 7 with the value of column-1/column-17/column-7 row Nth. And to each cell with value is not "Valid" row Nth, fill the looped sheet (column A to C) start from row 20 with the value of column-1/column-17/column-7 row Nth.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim arr: Dim sh
Dim cnt1 As Integer: Dim cnt2 As Integer: Dim i As Integer
Dim rgValid As Range: Dim rgNotValid As Range

With Sheets("DATA") 'change as needed
Set rg = .Range("L2", .Range("L2").End(xlDown)) 'change as needed
End With

arr = Array(1, 14, 7) 'change as needed

For Each sh In Sheets
If Not rg.Find(sh.Range("A5").Value) Is Nothing And sh.Name <> "DATA" Then

    With rg
    .Replace sh.Range("A5").Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        With .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -3)
        cnt1 = Application.CountA(.Cells): cnt2 = Application.CountIf(.Cells, "Valid")
        If cnt1 = cnt2 Then
            Set rgValid = .Cells: Set rgNotValid = .End(xlDown)
        ElseIf cnt2 = 0 Then
            Set rgNotValid = .Cells: Set rgValid = .End(xlDown)
        ElseIf cnt1 <> cnt2 And cnt2 <> 0 Then
            .Replace "Valid", "", xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rgValid = .SpecialCells(xlBlanks): Set rgNotValid = .SpecialCells(xlConstants)
            rgValid.Value = "Valid"
        End If
        End With
    .Replace True, sh.Range("A5").Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With

    Set rgValid = rgValid.Offset(0, -8)
    Set rgNotValid = rgNotValid.Offset(0, -8)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
        rgValid.Offset(0, arr(i - 1) - 1).Copy Destination:=sh.Cells(7, i) 'change as needed
        rgNotValid.Offset(0, arr(i - 1) - 1).Copy Destination:=sh.Cells(20, i) 'change as needed
    Next

End If
Next

End Sub
```

rg is the range of name in sheet DATA column L. There must be no blank cell within this rg.

arr is an array variable with the expected column sequence number. In this example case, the sequence is : column A, column N and column G ---> 1,14,7. In your case, it will be : 1,9,42,4,14,16,40,12.

Then it loop to each sheet other than sheet DATA as sh variable, and get the name which resides in each looped sheet cell A5.

Then in sheet DATA column L, it get the range of cell.offset(0,-3), which value is that name. So, the range is column I (because offset 0,-3). Within this range in column I, it counts how many data are there as cnt1, and count how many data with words "Valid" as cnt2.

If cnt1 = cnt2 then it means in the range of that name, column I all have "Valid" value. So it create a range for all those Valid value as rgValid variable, and create a range which value is blank as rgNotValid variable.

If cnt2 = 0 then it means in the range for that name, column I doesn't have a "Valid" value at all. So it create a range for all those not Valid value as rgNotValid variable, and create a range which value is blank as rgValid variable.

if cnt1 <> cnt2 and cnt2 <> 0 then it means some value within the range for that name has "Valid" value, some not. So it create a range for all those Valid value as rgValid variable, and create a range which value is not "Valid" as rgNotValid variable.

Finally it loop as many as the item in arr to put the expected value to each looped sheet column A to C starting from row 7 for the Valid value, starting from row 20 for the not Valid value.

Please note, the code assumes that in sheet DATA column I and column L, there'll be no blank cell in between row of data.